# How to test a function inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

If I have a function like this:

```
def any_function(type_name, field_name):
    def another_function(name):
        ...
```

How would I go about testing `any_function`?

In case I used the wrong definition of testing, I mean by writing 
`print(any_function(...))`

Comment: What does `any_function` do? Is `another_function` being used locally, or returned?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For testing and debugging purposes only, put a `globlal another_function` statement at the start, but don't forget to remove it post-testing. This will make you able to debug that inner function after calling the outer function once to initialise it. Otherwise, since `another_function()` will be in the local scope of `any_function()`, put your debugging inside `any_function()`.

```
def any_function(type_name, field_name):
    global another_function  # Delete line in functional versions
    def another_function(name):
        pass

any_function(None, None)
print(another_function(...))
```

Or

```
def any_function(type_name, field_name):
    def another_function(name):
        pass
    print(another_function(...))  # Delete line in functional versions

any_function(None, None)
```

Answer (score 8):

You wouldn't test an inner function. You'd just test the functionality of the outer function; the inner function is an implementation detail, not the API presented by the unit. You'd normally use an inner function to produce a closure, making the inner function dependent on the scope.

Now, if the inner function is returned by the outer, test that return value, like you would the product of any function.

If the inner function *is* independent and requires tests of its own, you shouldn't be nesting it.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi you test the outer function. If the outer function affects a variable outside the function, test that interaction. It doesn't matter if that interaction was achieved using a nested function.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi I am stating that there is no point in testing the inner function *in isolation*. You test the whole unit, e.g. what the outer function produces. You wouldn't try and extract individual statements from the outer function to test those either. An inner function is no different. It is part of the whole.

Comment: and I disagree. Perfect example is creating a decorator. You absolutely want to test the inner function of that decorator function to ensure it's correct.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi: yes, because then *that's the product* of the outer function. Where did you get the impression that I think that that should be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `another_function` was deleted by mistake. Write a test to catch that.

Now imagine `another_function` is back again. How can you tell?

Imagine some code in `another_function` is deleted, or changed in some way by mistake. Write a test to detect that error.

Answer (score 0):

A function creates a function to either a) use it or b) return it. In Python, b) is probably more common than a).  Martijn Pieters covered a).  For b), testing the outer function means calling it and then testing the function returned.  One should usually do that for more than one set of inputs to the outer function, which is to say, for more than one returned function.  An example:

```
import unittest as u

def adder(n):
    return lambda m: m+n

class Test(u.TestCase):
    def test_adder(self):
        add3 = adder(3)
        self.assertEqual((add3(-1), add3(0), add3(1)), (2, 3, 4))
        add_3 = adder(-3)
        self.assertEqual((add_3(-1), add_3(0), add_3(1)), (-4,-3,-2))

u.main()
```